# sharepoint notify new items to list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I'm creating a sharepoint hosted app, two pages, default.aspx and admin.aspx.
When I update the list in the appweb thru a function in default.aspx, I want that a notify windows will popup to the client that are watching the admin.aspx page, that a new items is added to the list.

Is that possible in sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the same, but I think "AJAX automatic refresh can help". See this article: http://www.rdacorp.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-auto-refresh-web-parts-with-ajax-options/